# Stereoselectivity of the homogeneous catalytic hydrogenation of 2-Methylenebicyclo[2.2.1]heptane using wilkinson's catalyst

Tags: organic-chemistry

For the following reaction, 2 products are available: in one, the methyl group is axial, and in the other, it is equatorial.

[image]

The addition of hydrogen to the double bond is a syn addition to the less sterically hindered side of the bond, but how can I know which side is more sterically hindered in this case? Is the "bottom" face with 2 methylene groups more hindered than the "top" face with only one methylene group? or are there other factors to consider (such as the stability of an equatorial methyl group compared to an axial one)?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It'd be better if you put the complete reaction in the attachment.